# Failed to call verify() a mock that is proxied by MethodValidationPostProcessor

Tags: java, validation, testing, mockito, spring-test

I have a simple service interface:

```java
@Service
@Validated
public interface UserService
{
    void createUser (@Email String userEmail);

    void refreshUsers ();
}
```

I want to test 2 things on `UserService`:

1. The validation annotation `@Email` is working.
2. The calls on method `refreshUsers()` can be verified by `verify()`.

Therefore, I created the following test case with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`:

```java
@RunWith(value = SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = UserServiceTest.TestConfig.class)
public class UserServiceTest
{
    @Configuration
    public static class TestConfig
    {
        @Bean
        public UserService userService ()
        {
            return mock(UserService.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor ()
        {
            return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    public void createUserWithValidEmail ()
    {
        userService.createUser("aaa@example.com");
    }

    @Test
    public void createUserWithInvalidEmail ()
    {
        assertThatThrownBy(() -> userService.createUser("aaa"))
            .isInstanceOf(ConstraintViolationException.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void refreshUsersCalled1 ()
    {
        userService.refreshUsers();
        verify(userService).refreshUsers();
    }

    @Test
    public void refreshUsersCalled2 ()
    {
        userService.refreshUsers();
        verify(userService).refreshUsers();
    }
```

The test case `refreshUsersCalled2()` will fail with the following message:

```
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

However, the method `refreshUsers()` is not one of final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.

After some investigation, I found that the problem came from the conflict between `mock()` and `MethodValidationPostProcessor`.

If I remove the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` Spring bean from `TestConfig`, the above issues will be solved. However, the test case `createUserWithInvalidEmail` will fail because the validation mechanism is gone.

Is there any way to test both validation and `verify()` in the same test?

The full example is at https://github.com/johnlinp/misc-demo/tree/master/mockito-with-validation-in-spring-test.

Comment: If you debug your test, when you inspect your ```UserService```, is it Mockito mock?

Comment: Yes, it shows "com.sun.proxy$Proxy36@3638 Mock for UserService, hashCode: 2120493960".